# Select pandas frame rows based on two columns' values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I wish to select some specific rows based on two column values. For example:

```
d = {'user' : [1., 2., 3., 4] ,'item' : [5., 6., 7., 8.],'f1' : [9., 16., 17., 18.], 'f2':[4,5,6,5], 'f3':[4,5,5,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print df

Out:
   f1  f2  f3  item  user
0   9   4   4     5     1
1  16   5   5     6     2
2  17   6   5     7     3
3  18   5   8     8     4
```

I want to select the rows based on the values of 'user' and 'item'. Given an 2d numpy array which stores the [user, item] values pairs:

```
samples = np.array([[1,5],[3,7],[3,7],[2,6]]) 
Out: 
array([[1, 5],
       [3, 7],
       [3, 7],
       [2, 6]])
```

Then the expected output is:

```
    Out:
   f1  f2  f3  item  user
0   9   4   4     5     1
2  17   6   5     7     3
2  17   6   5     7     3
1  16   5   5     6     2
```

Then, my final objective is to get an 2d numpy array stores all the columns values except item and user, which is:

```
Out: 
array([[9, 4, 4],
       [17, 6, 5],
       [17, 6, 5],
       [16, 5, 5]])
```

As we can see, it is the values of columns f1, f2, f3.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you make `samples` a DataFrame with columns `user` and `item`, then you can obtain the desired values with an [inner join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra). By default, `pd.merge` merges on all columns of `samples` and `df` shared in common -- in this case, that would be `user` and `item`. Hence,

```
result = pd.merge(samples, df, how='inner')
```

yields

```
   user  item  f1  f2  f3
0     1     5   9   4   4
1     3     7  17   6   5
2     3     7  17   6   5
3     2     6  16   5   5
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'user' : [1., 2., 3., 4] ,'item' : [5., 6., 7., 8.],'f1' : [9., 16., 17., 18.], 'f2':[4,5,6,5], 'f3':[4,5,5,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
samples = np.array([[1,5],[3,7],[3,7],[2,6]]) 
samples = pd.DataFrame(samples, columns=['user', 'item'])

result = pd.merge(samples, df, how='inner')
result = result[['f1', 'f2', 'f3']]
result = result.values
print(result)
```

yields

```
[[  9.   4.   4.]
 [ 17.   6.   5.]
 [ 17.   6.   5.]
 [ 16.   5.   5.]]
```

Comment: Wow! @unutbu, that is great! Thanks! That is what I want, because I don't want to use for loop.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that is a bit `numpy` array *inclined* -

```
import numpy as np

# Convert item and user columns to a 2-column array
item_user_arr = np.asarray(df[["item","user"]]).astype(int)

# Mask of matches across rows of samples and item_user_arr, with columns flipped
mask = (samples[:,None,1]==item_user_arr[:,0]) & (samples[:,None,0]==item_user_arr[:,1])

# Get indices of matches
_,C = np.where(mask)

# Use those indices to select data from f1,f2,f3 columns for final output array
out = np.asarray(df[["f1","f2","f3"]])[C,:]
```

Output for given inputs -

```
In [536]: out
Out[536]: 
array([[  9.,   4.,   4.],
       [ 17.,   6.,   5.],
       [ 17.,   6.,   5.],
       [ 16.,   5.,   5.]])
```

Comment: Thanks @Divakar, this is also an excellent way to handle this problem!